# Is it possible to know who liked my website page/post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to know who are the people who liked my websites page/post. (I'm talking about like buttons inside websites and not on a simple facebook page, just to make this issue clear).

I googled this issue, and most of the answers were that I just cant do something like this, but found one answer of someone who said that I can use this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.0

to find out who liked my website page/post, But he didn't explain. 
I'm not an expert, but if that's true and I can pull out the names of the users that liked my website page/post, they should first accept that their private info is being passed to an outer source.

Anyway, I didn't understand anything from the page and how this thing should help me solve the problem.

Thanks for the help and your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible IMHO. The events do not Return any user data, as described in the docs.

But if you're using the JS SDK and have authenticated Users on your website, you could use the "edge.created" event in conjunction with the Element ID of the like button to find out the user liked the page/post.

Comment: As I thought.. 
Thank you :)